# Trying to add BarButtonItem to programmatically created NavigationController

Tags: objective-c

I have pushed a view controller embedded in a navigation controller after tapping a button in my app. I am trying to add a "SAVE" button in the right corner of the nav bar. However, with this code it is not showing up. My assumption is that it is not showing up because `nc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` should be placed in `viewWillAppear`. Since `nc` is programmatically created and does not have a class file with `viewWillAppear` how can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)editProfileButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    FXFormViewController *vc = [[FXFormViewController alloc] init];
    vc.formController.form = [[PersonalContactInfoForm alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    nc.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(105/255.0)
                                                                             green:(210/255.0)
                                                                              blue:(231/255.0)
                                                                             alpha:1.0];

    // WHY IS THIS BUTTON NOT BEING ADDED?
    nc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

    [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Do it in FXFormViewController `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: I do not have a class file for `FXFormViewController` because it is programmatically created with a library I am using. The library files I have are FXForms.h and FXForms.m. It is created somewhere in those files. Would I be able to add it to the `viewWillAppear` in FXForms.m? @Jkmn

Comment: Try `vc.formController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` uses the `-navigationItem` of the currently displayed view controller. Try this instead:

`vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...`

Answer (score -1):

Here you can take advantage of a powerful feature of OOP called `Inheritance`.

Create a Class say `MyFXFormViewController` inherited from `FXFormViewController`.

## MyFXFormViewController.h

```
#import "FXFormViewController.h"

@interface MyFXFormViewController : FXFormViewController

@end
```

## MyFXFormViewController.m

```
#import "MyFXFormViewController.h"
@implementation MyFXFormViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem  *saveBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveBarButton;
}
```

And your previous code should be like

```
- (IBAction)editProfileButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    MyFXFormViewController *vc = [[MyFXFormViewController alloc] init];
    vc.formController.form = [[PersonalContactInfoForm alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    nc.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    nc.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(105/255.0)
                                                                             green:(210/255.0)
                                                                              blue:(231/255.0)
                                                                             alpha:1.0];

    [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```